# Magento 1.8.1: media directory bug if using symlink

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, magento-1.8

I am having trouble with my Magento install, in the CMS when I go to insert an image with the wysiwig editor the folder keeps opening repeatedly.

The folder structure should be:

```
- infortis
    - brands
    - fortis
    - ultimo
```

But what I get is:

```
-infortis
    -infortis
        -infortis
            -infortis
                -infortis
```

And this just keeps repeating.

Magento Version 1.8.1. Any help appreciated.

Comment: just to verify, are you using any 3th party extensions or plugins for you editor or media browser? Does this happen on other PC's/browsers as well? Is the directory structure in the `media/wysiwyg` directory correct? and last: are you getting any javascript errors when opening the editor or the image uploader? Sorry for all the questions, just trying to get a better picture of the issue :)

Comment: @sandermangel I can confirm that this is a problem we are also having the same issue :( seems that `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images` does not deal well with links

Comment: Same problem confirmed on EE 1.13.1.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found that the following edits makes it work as expected, and works with non-symlinked (dev) resources as well:

In the same class as `mentiond Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images`, apply these patches:

```
# This patch file was generated by NetBeans IDE
# It uses platform neutral UTF-8 encoding and \n newlines.
--- <html>Images.php (<b>Today 4:14:50 PM</b>)</html>
+++ <html><b>Current File</b></html>
@@ -223,7 +223,7 @@
     public function getCurrentUrl()
     {
         if (!$this->_currentUrl) {
-            $path = str_replace(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir(), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
+            $path = str_replace(realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir()), '', $this->getCurrentPath());
             $path = trim($path, DS);
             $this->_currentUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($this->_storeId)->getBaseUrl('media') .
                                  $this->convertPathToUrl($path) . '/';



# This patch file was generated by NetBeans IDE
# It uses platform neutral UTF-8 encoding and \n newlines.
--- <html>Images.php (<b>f47f0ff</b>)</html>
+++ <html><b>Current File</b></html>
@@ -68,7 +68,7 @@
      */
     public function getStorageRoot()
     {
-        return Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir() . DS . Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY
+        return realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir()) . DS . Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY
             . DS;
     }
```

Comment: I have raised a bug for this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=16088

Comment: This seems to break the thumbnails of the image popup in the wysiwyg editor though.. it fails to put "wysiwyg" in the url, so it looks like this: `https://blabla.com/media//.thumbs/img.png?rand=1399016538 `Will debug when I get the chance

Comment: @Erfan Been there, done that:) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/magento-1-8-1-0-wysiwyg-editor-is-not-displaying-thumbnails-in-image-manager

Comment: I've bundled this fix up in a mini-module if anyone finds it useful: https://github.com/eyemagine/Magento-MediaSymlink

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobbins, you're plugin did the trick! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue in `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images::convertIdToPath`

The core code is as follows.

```
public function convertIdToPath($id)
{
    $path = $this->idDecode($id);
    if (!strstr($path, $this->getStorageRoot())) {
        $path = $this->getStorageRoot() . $path;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

And the fix is to use realpath when getting the storage root as follows.

```
public function convertIdToPath($id)
{
    $path = $this->idDecode($id);
    $realpath = $this->getStorageRoot();
    if (is_link(rtrim($realpath,'/'))) {
        $realpath = realpath($realpath);
    }
    if (!strstr($path, $realpath)) {
        $path = $realpath . $path;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

So what we have done is to rewrite `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images` and use the updated converIdToPath function. I found the original solution [on a German website](http://blog.muench-worms.de/magento-sicherheitspatch-und-defekter-wysiwyg-dateibrowser/), but that will break if say you have a dev system without links and another system with a link.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this issue as well and I wanted to share a little more info to save the next person some time.  If you are running the Magento Enterprise Edition and have an active support agreement in place there is an official patch available.  Just open a support ticket and request the patch directly.  The patch name is "PATCH_SUPEE-2662_EE_1.13.1.0_v1".